# Debian Buster LXQt cannot place icons to desktop edge

Tags: desktop, icons, lxqt

can anyone help me with this please? I cannot seem to place icons on the desktop to the edge of the screen. There is a gap on the left and a much larger gap to the right where I cannot place icons since they snap back. I am using LXQt on Debian Buster 10.10.

I tried all the settings with no luck. I also tried dconf-editor but did not find any related option there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Turned out the label text under the icons was a bit large and did not fit in the edges, causing the window manager to snap them back to the first relevant space.